How to use cicflowmeter python package
Can anyone please guide me how can I use cicflowmeter python package to convert from pcap packets into csv not from shell promt, but from python code. Like I want to comvert packets through notebook(ipynb/py).
I tried converting packet but it keeps on giving me error, maybe I am using it wrong or something, I know how to convert from CMD/power shell but I want to use package in python code to convert it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
